# How do I change the selected Value of a combo box from a window button when combo box is binded with enumList in its own viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, visual-studio-2017

I have two Windows and several user controls in my project, one of the user control **Ribbon** is placed on **MainWindow**.

The **Ribbon** is **groupBox** user control containing a **comboBox** which is **binded with enum PackageType** as follows:

```
namespace ManglamStellaris.ViewModels
{
    public class RibbonViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public event Action<PackageType> OnPackageSelection;

        public RibbonViewModel()
        {

            ListPackageType = new List<Tuple<PackageType, string>>(new Tuple<PackageType, string>[]
            {
                   new Tuple<PackageType, string>(PackageType.Raw, "Raw"),
                   new Tuple<PackageType, string>(PackageType.Lagna, "Lagna"),
                   new Tuple<PackageType, string>(PackageType.LaalKitab, "LaalKitab")

            });

        }
        
        public List<Tuple<PackageType, String>> ListPackageType { get; private set; }

        public PackageType packageType
        {
            get { return _packageType; }
            set
            {
                _packageType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("packageType");

                if (OnPackageSelection != null)
                {
                    OnPackageSelection(_packageType);
                }
            }
        }

        private PackageType _packageType;

    }
}
```

An enum PackageType is defined in enums.cs:

```
 public enum PackageType
    {
        Raw,
        Lagna,
        LaalKitab
    }
```

**RibbonViewModel** is initialized in **MainViewModel** as follows:

```
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        Dictionary<Type, object> _Services = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        public event Action<PackageType> OnPackageSelection;
        public MainViewModel() {
            Config = new ConfigViewModel();
            Input = new InputViewModel();
            Result = new CalculationResultViewModel();
            RibbonViewModel = new RibbonViewModel();
            RibbonViewModel.OnPackageSelection += (PackageType) => {
                if (OnPackageSelection != null) {
                    OnPackageSelection(PackageType);
                }
            };

            DoCalculationCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
                DoCalculation();
            });
        }
```

**MainWindow controls the user control shown in the content control area of Main Window based on selection type:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainViewModel ViewModel;

        public ResultView ResultView;
        public LagnaChart LagnaChart;
        public LaalKitab LaalKitab;

        public MainWindow(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = mainViewModel;
            ViewModel.OnPackageSelection += (PackageType) => {
                if (PackageType == PackageType.LaalKitab)
                {
                    this.mainContentArea.Content = LaalKitab;
                }
                else if (PackageType == PackageType.Lagna)
                {
                    this.mainContentArea.Content = LagnaChart;
                }
                else if (PackageType == PackageType.Raw)
                {
                    this.mainContentArea.Content = ResultView;
                }
            };

            DataContext = ViewModel;

            ResultView = new ResultView(ViewModel);
            LagnaChart = new LagnaChart(ViewModel);
            LaalKitab = new LaalKitab(ViewModel);

            this.mainContentArea.Content = ResultView;
        }
    }
```

How can I select the combo box value from another Window Button Click function which is as follows:

```
  public partial class HomeWindow : Window
    {

        public LagnaChart LagnaChart;
        MainViewModel _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
       
        public HomeWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
          
            DataContext = _mainViewModel;
        }
 private void LaalKitab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(_mainViewModel);
            _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
           
            DataContext = _mainViewModel;
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
```

**Function LaalKitab opens a window but how to set the value of comboBox in the LaalKitab function itself and pass it so it changes the user control in Main Window content area?
It works perfectly when I change the value from comboDropdown at runtime.
Thanks in advance**

Comment: You must bind `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to a property of the view model that also contains the `ComboBox.ItemsSource`. Every class that wants to set the selected item must have a reference to this view model and assign a value to the binding source of the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Yes, it has a property package type and in successfully fixed it by calling its reference in MainViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

In HomeWindow.xaml.cs when button is pressed it simply creates new instance of main window and set its package type using the bold line in below code.

```
 private void LaalKitab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(_mainViewModel);
             //This is how I change the combo box selection.
            _mainViewModel.RibbonViewModel.packageType = PackageType.Lagna;

            _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
           
            DataContext = _mainViewModel;
           
            mainWindow.Show();
            
        }
```